# Big O. Вложенный цикл с if

Tags: алгоритм, циклы, сложность

В общих чертах, ситуация следующая:

Я имею такой код:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
     if(condition)
     {
         for(...){ }
     {
     else
     {
         for(...){ }
     }

}
```

И такой:

```
void function(int b)
{
     if(b <= 0)
        return;
     if(condition)
     {
        function(b - 1);
        function(b - 1);
     }
}
```

Как должны рассчитываться сложности этих алгоритмов?

Comment: я вызываю Function(100). Сколько раз функция вызовется рекурсивно?

Comment: @tym32167, я понимаю, к чему вы клоните, но я хотел бы узнать формулу, по которой это можно рассчитать

Comment: см тему "рекуррентные соотношения"

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первый код — нет никаких данных. Мало ли что у вас в циклах крутится... Поэтому просто нет данных.

Второй — ну, пусть время работы `f(b)` равно `t(b)`. Тогда в *худшем случае* (`condition` всегда 'true') имеем:

```
t(b) = 2*t(b-1)
```

(временем проверки условия пренебрежем). Вот и выходит, что если `t(0) = C` (какой-то константе), то `t(n) = С*2^n`. Вот и ответ: O(2<sup>n</sup>).

Comment: Допустим, что циклы зависят от входных данных и имеют в себе какие-нибудь математические вычисления, которые не влияют на итоговую сложность

Comment: **КАК ИМЕННО** зависят от входных данных? Например, `for(int i = 0; i < n*n; ++i)...`? :)

Comment: самым обычным образом. К примеру, `for(int i = 0, i < n, i++)`

Comment: С запятыми? Код не компилируется :) Если там будут точки с запятыми, то время выполнения такого цикла - n раз некоторое константное время - O(n) - в любом случае, не зависимо от `condition`. Поскольку внешний цикл выполняется 10 раз - независимо от n! - то время работы всего кода остается O(n).

Comment: А в случае, если под if будут последовательно стоять два цикла, то сложности будут складываться?

Comment: Будут. Только вот тут своеобразные правила сложения... O(n) + O(n) == O(n) :)

Comment: Да, это я знаю, спасибо